# Register Components Based on appsetting value?

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container, castle

Does Castle windsor offer a cleaner or recommended way of performing registration based on an appsettings value in the app.config/web.config? Example of what i am doing now is below

```
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseFakeEmailService"] == "true")
        {
            container.Register(Component.For<IEmailService>().ImplementedBy<EmailService>().IsFallback().LifestyleTransient());
            container.Register(Component.For<IEmailLogger>().ImplementedBy<EmailLogger>().LifestylePerThread());
        }
        else
        {
            container.Register(Component.For<IEmailService>().ImplementedBy<FakeEmailService>().IsFallback().LifestyleTransient());
            container.Register(Component.For<IEmailLogger>().ImplementedBy<FakeEmailLogger>().IsFallback().LifestyleTransient());
        }
```

Comment: I would say that what you're doing now is the recommended approach.

Comment: @Steven I was trying to find a good way to indicate that this is not really the recommended way of using Castle in my answer. What do you think of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to clean this kind of writing up. The first coming to mind would be to declare a factory method as the way to create your component:

```
Component.For<IEmailService>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => (configValue ? new EmailService() as IEmailService: new DummyEmailService() as IEmailService))
```

If you really want to get fancy, or if you have many classes that follow this pattern, you could have a look at custom [resolvers](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Resolvers.ashx) that can help you determine what to return at runtime.

There is also the `IsDefault` filter mechanism that can help you determine what component to resolve by default:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IDummy>().ImplementedBy<TestDummy>().IsDefault(t => isTestMode == true)
    );
```

But if you want to register only the types that are relevant to your mode, then you are doing the right thing. You can perhaps push the installation in a `IWindsorInstaller` to isolate it but I know of no other mechanism to handle it.

EDIT: and I should have looked harder, there are [conditional registration mechanisms](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Conditional-component-registration.ashx)

Comment: A lot of interesting options, but they all enable hot-swapping dependencies, without restarting the application. If you have to restart the application anyway (because it is a configuration switch as is the case with the OP), the preferred solution should IMO be to leave Castle's configuration as simple as possible. Castle's diagnostic services will b e unaware of the existence of such switch and will make it blind. Same holds for any integration test you write to automatically test the container's configuration for correctness.

Comment: You're right about the hot swap, I'm swimming in it atm, which is why I was bothered by the conditional registration. When you say to KISS Castle configuration though, I cringe a bit because I personally don't like including test classes in a release, hence my proposition just not to build the test classes when releasing, and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you want to register dependencies using XML configuration, then you should use  [Windsor XML Configuration](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.XML-Registration-Reference.ashx).

This is another example from [Windsor documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components.ashx)

```
<components>
  <component
      id="notification"
      service="Acme.Crm.Services.INotificationService, Acme.Crm"
      type="Acme.Crm.Services.EmailNotificationService, Acme.Crm"
  </component>
</components>
```

Comment: IMO, you should only use XML configuration if assemblies are dynamically loaded and can't be resolved statically during compile-time, because XML configuration is much more verbose and error prone than configuration through code.

Comment: you're right, but so does app.config. If the configuration is complicated, then using windsor XML configuration is a better approach IMO.